# how to restart apache camel application with using database and jms

Tags: java, database, apache-camel

In production, prod supporters need to restart the application for deploying new release.

The application will consume data from internet, transform data and save data into database.

For example, data A1 will be put into queue Q1. Then data A2 will be saved into database and be sent to next queue Q2.

However, if A2 is saved into db and at the same time prod supporters will be restarted application, what I saw is that A2 will be saved into db twice.

What I am thinking is:

1. A2 is saved and about to be sent to next queue.
2. Application shuts down.
3. A2 is not able to be sent to next queue Q2. JMS transaction failed. A1 is re-put on queue Q1.
4. Application restarts successfully.
5. A1 is consumed again. Application generates A2 and saves A2 again into database.
6. A2 is sent to next queue Q2.

The problem is there are duplicates in database.

So how do I fix this? I don't want duplicates. And also apparently, the constraints cannot be set into database, otherwise, A2 will never be sent to next queue Q2.

Thank you!

================ Updated =================

**Truth**:

```
org.springframework.jms.IllegalStateException: The Session is closed; nested exception is javax.jms.IllegalStateException: The Session is closed
```

The message cannot be delivered correctly when session is closed. Thus next time when application is restarted, the application will re-process the message and call method again to write data into database.

**Reason**:

The jms session is closed before application shutting down camel.

**Fix**:

```
<camel:camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" id="xxx-camel-context" depends-on="hibernateTransactionManager, jmsTransactionManager">
```

Add transaction manager to camel context.

In this way, camel context will shutdown completely before spring destroying transaction manager.

Comment: How did you setup the transaction? You can take a look at the camel in action chapter 9 for more information.

Comment: Can you post your route (or an example that reproduces the problem) include the transaction managers you are using. Alternatively, you could change your code to explicitly check for duplicates before insert or make sure Camel shuts down gracefully: http://camel.apache.org/graceful-shutdown.html

Comment: I checked the logs and found out that there were not many `inflight and pending exchanges` when the application was shutting down. Weird.

Comment: Have you read http://activemq.apache.org/should-i-use-xa.html? I could be wrong but I don't see anything in your code to tie together the JMS and database transaction.

Comment: We save infos into database at the end of queue, thus we didn't implement xa transaction. Normally, if database commits successfully, the message should be immediately sent to next queue. The problem is restarting application causes some weird actions. I am trying to find out the issue about restarting application.